# java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Thursday 30 May 2019 - 02:00 PM' could not be parsed at index 0

Tags: java, selenium

I need to convert the string "Thursday 30 May 2019 - 02:00 PM" to (dd MMM hh:mm a) DateTimeFormat "06 June 01:54 PM"(date).

Here is my code:

```java
// last update date is : Thursday 30 May 2019 - 02:00 PM 
String lastUpadte WebUI.getText(findTestObject("Stock prices/date time"));
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d-MMM-yyyy");
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(lastUpadte, formatter);
System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + date);
```

[image]

Comment: `"d-MMM-yyyy"` will not be able to parse `"Thursday 30 May 2019 - 02:00 PM"`...

Comment: Thursday 30 May 2019 - 02:00 PM to any parse format? I need to compare with ( 06 June 01:54 PM) something date like this

Comment: You'll need to convert both, but will need a different pattern for each.

Comment: It is possible to convert both of them to a `LocalDateTime` and then compare them. You just have to use different `String` patterns for each one, as @Marit correctly pointed out. Find some useful information about it in [the JavaDocs of `DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

Comment: bit of difficult to find out the pattern for "Thursday 30 May 2019 - 02:00 PM"

Comment: I didn’t get that, sorry. What do you mean that you want a date? `06 June 01:54 PM` is date *and time* . Or did you want `d-MMM-yyyy` format (`6-Jun-2019`)?

Comment: both string into one format, yes with date and time(not important the year)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dates and times were revamped for Java 8, introducing types like LocalDateTime which are very easy to use.  The lack of a year in one of your date strings is an added complexity, but using these features, you could have :

```
    String dtStr1 = "06 June 01:54 PM"; 
    DateTimeFormatter formatter1 = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("dd MMMM hh:mm a")
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.YEAR, 2019)
            .toFormatter();
    LocalDateTime date1 = LocalDateTime.parse(dtStr1, formatter1);

    String dtStr2 = "Thursday 30 May 2019 - 02:00 PM";  
    DateTimeFormatter formatter2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE dd MMM uuuu - hh:mm a");
    LocalDateTime date2 = LocalDateTime.parse(dtStr2, formatter2);

    System.out.println(date1);
    System.out.println(date2);
```

Output is :

`2019-06-06T13:54
 2019-05-30T14:00`

The formatter patterns are listed in :
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Comment: Good answer, thanks. I suppose we can’t be sure whether `May` is the full month name or an abbreviation since the name is already so short. So we may need either `MMM` for an abbreviation or `MMMM` for full month name.

Comment: hey, this is working perfectly , at some point  i have got below exception.. Reason:
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Monday 3 June 2019 - 01:00 PM' could not be parsed at index 7
https://stackoverflow.com/users/681444/racraman

Comment: EEEE d MMMM uuuu - hh:mm a , was worked , thanks again mate, great stuff here

Comment: Great - glad to hear it helped.  All the best :)

Answer (score 2):

To get a `java.time.LocalDateTime` with the same format as "Thursday 30 May 2019 - 02:00 PM":

```java
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("Thursday 30 May 2019 - 02:00 PM", 
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE dd MMMM uuuu '-' hh':'mm a")));
```

For those with the same format as "06 June 01:54 PM":

```java
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
   .appendPattern("dd MMMM hh':'mm a")
   .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.YEAR, 2019)
   .toFormatter();
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("06 June 01:54 PM", formatter));
```

Note we need to specifically build the parser this way in the latter example since the year is missing, otherwise we'll get an Exception.